# Merge Order Of Multiple Branches

Tags: git, merge

I'm having some trouble figuring out the best order of merging branches to avoid merge conflicts and easier code reviews. I'm going to use the following picture to diagram my situation.

[image]

As you can see, I made Branch V from master, and added some commits. Then I also have Branch K which was branched off of Branch V, and also has some commits. I want to have two merge requests up for people to review, so my original plan was to have Branch K set to merge into Branch V, and then Branch V to merge into master.

Is that the best strategy? I didn't want to set Branch K to merge into master, because in the code review, the diff between Branch K and master includes differences that were made Branch V's commits.

I just really want to know what the best merge order is. Thanks!

Comment: Are there commits on branch V after the split of branch K (not shown in the diagram)? Or does V really just turn into K as shown?

Comment: @matt K is always going to branch off the front of Branch V. If it gets behind at all, I will rebase branch K to be at the front of V.

Comment: In that case, as shown in the diagram, there is no meaningful Branch V. Just merge K into master.

Comment: Gotcha. Now for some context, someone was developing on Branch V and I was making new features but needed branch v's content in it. I branched off of Branch V to do that. Do you think there was a better alternative?

Comment: No. As long as you and "someone" remain in close contact, that is exactly the way to behave. The same thing happened to me the other day; "someone" was working on a feature branch and said, "help me with this, work on the following subfeature". So I branched in the expectation of merging into the feature branch. No PR for that; it's just the pair of us working together. You could do that too, but there's no point; it would be a fast-forward. :) When my friend was all done with the feature branch, then it was time for the PR.

Comment: Indeed, on many occasions, working on a feature branch, I take out a subbranch _myself_ to explore a line of thought. But then, again, there is no PR; this is just me working, and I can just merge with myself if things work out. The PR is for when I'm all done.

Comment: One more thing: in real life, it can be nicer to do this just before the PR: rebase onto master; squash or otherwise rejigger the commits on the branch; push. Now request the PR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, making one PR from `V` to `master` and another from `K` to `V` makes the most sense from the point of view of **making those PRs easy to review**, as each PR will only show its relevant code changes. And I would argue that making life easier on reviewers should be your top priority.

Once these PRs are approved for merge you could either:

1. first merge `K` -> `V` and then `V` -> `master`
2. first merge `K` -> `master` and then change the base of the other PR to `master` and merge it as well

for option 2. to work well, `K` needs to make sense on its own, because you shouldn't at any point merge something broken into `master`

if you choose option 1. I would also suggest to edit the `V` -> `master` PR description after the merge of `K` to reflect that it now holds more (approved) changes

and in general I would suggest to use the PR description to describe the relation between the two PRs in order to give the reviewers the full picture